# Can a program log your browser activity with taskbar names?

Tags: privacy, web-browser

There's [this old reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/43lqyb/why_is_discord_recording_our_open_programs_and/) where the OP notes that Discord's desktop client regularly logs the processes on your computer using QueryNameInformationFile, then claims that Discord "proceeds to take the names of everything you have open (this includes the titles of all your browsing windows)" and send it to its servers, but without explaining how he reached that conclusion.

Most browsers display the name of the webpage you're currently viewing as their taskbar name. Could a program such as Discord log this information and see your browsing history through it? And is there a way to check if a program is doing that?

I'm not talking about a program being able to just see that I'm running chrome.exe, but also see the names of my open tabs on Chrome, or at least of the tab I'm currently viewing.

Comment: Wow, that's a strangely hard API to find solid documentation about. Both Bing and Google think you mean NtQueryInformationFile, but there are plenty of other references to QueryNameInformationFile, almost all out of Sysinternals tools.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it:

```
C:\Users\dandavis>tasklist -v |find "chrome"
...
chrome.exe                   11364 Console                    1    782,600 K Running         DAND\dandavis
3:26:35 privacy - Can a program log your browser activity with taskbar names? -
...
```

I didn't run that as an admin, so presumably any EXE can access the same listing. As it run inside a cmd instance, I would imagine it being very difficult/complex to detect, at least w/o modifying the OS.

If someone knows a way to programmatically "peek" inside command shells from outside, please share a link so I can update the answer with a more definitive assessment.